# How to add continual tick marks in a range depending on a value in Excel

Tags: excel

How I can add continual tick marks in a range depending on a number value.

e.g B1 has number 10. So, I want 10 Tick Marks (Check Marks) in 10 rows in a column automatically using any formula or so.

[image]

Comment: What have you researched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First format the cells in column **C** with the `Marlett` font.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=IF($B$1="","",IF(ROW()>$B$1,"","a"))
```

and copy downwards.  Then put your value in **B1**.  For  example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My answer is similar, just used a different font and char(252)

```
=IF(ROW()<=$B$1,CHAR(252),"")
```

Then drag down

-
[image]